# Convert c++ executable program to shared object

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have an strange issue..  I have source code of JAGS software which I can compile in solaris i86 and it generates an executable file.. and it was working fine... now issue is

1. I want to call this executable file from JAVA and wish I was able to do that..
2. Now I want to use the same source code without executable file and want to create an shared object which can be triggered from java usin JNI.

Is it possible to modify the make file and generate a shared object instead of an executable file?

Comment: `is it possible to change modification is make file` [sic], well perhaps, but as it stands it is quite invisible (also, what is the issue? I see only a task, and no work)

Comment: It does not sound sensible. What is the software doing, why can't you just execute is as subprocess from Java and what do you expect from the JNI approach (JNI is quite a bit of work)?

Answer (score 0):

You can call an executable from java. Just a matter of:

```
String[] cmd = { "/path/to/program", "arg1", "arg2" };
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmd );
```

You can then use `proc` to communicate with the command via standard I/O streams, and to wait for it to finish.

Now if you wanted to go down the JNI path you will need to write some additional code to act as the JNI layer between the java and C. This layer is responsible for keeping track of the allocated C memory and converting between C data types and Java datatypes. This layer would then be able to call functions in your other source code (but probably not the main function). Then you need to modify/create a makefile which links your new JNI layer source code with the source code you already have into a .dll/.so. You then need to write the java class(es) that sit atop your JNI layer.

Which approach you choose really depends on what you want the native code to do, and how much interaction you need with it.